# Recommendations to AWS service types

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Good Day Everyone,

I am new to StackOverflow, do forgive me for any mistakes done.

I have been shifted to a programming department within my company, and as I have not explored AWS.

What I am required is to integrate some of their current services into one (including storing their data into one single server). Moving forward, I may need to be able to read/ write data and store them.

May I understand if only EC2 is required, or I may also need S3 for this?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Unfortunately your question is rather too open-ended for StackOverflow, which is focussed on programming Q&A. I suggest you ask on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws) where you will get many 'opinions' and people will engage you in a discussion on the topic to tease-out your requirements.

Comment: Looking at what you have posted, it is difficult to suggest or answer. If you post more details, such as what data is it, how you need to access and so on, it will be helpful. I also suggest try out services of EC2 and S3 as you have mentioned and post the questions if you are stuck.